# Gazebo model of a car with Ackermann steering

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm looking for a gazebo model of a car, more exactly a car with Ackermann steering. I know that there is a utility_cart model, but I'm looking for something which has more details (particularly around the front axis).

Thanks,

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3170/gazebo-model-of-a-car-with-ackermann-steering/) by [alex_rockt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/387/alex_rockt/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The drc_vehicle model in the [drcsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/b36170c2460b645c420a8e65c0f92139bf845990/gazebo_models/environments/drc_vehicle?at=default) repository has Ackermann steering implemented in the [DRCVehiclePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/b36170c2460b645c420a8e65c0f92139bf845990/plugins/DRCVehiclePlugin.cc?at=default) with PID controllers. I would be happier if the steering model used a mechanical linkage, but it works ok. There's some tutorials on driving it [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/VRC_Plugin_DRC_Vehicle).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1